# How to draw a colored border around Edit field using TShape?

Tags: delphi

I try to draw a colored border around TEdit field using TShape. I define the following component:

```
type TGEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    m_shape : TShape;
  protected
    procedure setBorderColor( brd_col : TColor );
    procedure setBorderWidth( brd_wid : integer );
  public
    constructor create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor  destroy(); override;
  published
    property borderColor : TColor read m_border_color write setBorderColor default clBlack;
    property borderWidth : integer read m_border_width write setBorderWidth default 1;
end;
```

Define a TShape object in constructor.

```
constructor TGEdit.create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.BorderStyle:= bsNone;
  m_border_color  := clBlack;
  m_border_width  := 1;
  m_shape         := TShape.Create(AOwner);
  m_shape.Parent  := Self.Parent;
  m_shape.Shape   := stRectangle;
  m_shape.Width   := Self.Width+2*m_border_width;
  m_shape.Height  := Self.Height+2*m_border_width;
  m_shape.Left    := Self.Left-m_border_width;
  m_shape.Top     := self.Top-m_border_width;
  m_shape.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  m_shape.Pen.Color   := m_border_color;
  m_shape.Pen.Style   := psSolid;
end;

destructor TGNumberEdit.destroy();
begin
  m_shape.Free();
  inherited;
end;
```

Define a procedures to change border's color and width

```
procedure TGEdit.setBorderColor( brd_col : TColor );
begin
  if m_border_color = brd_col then
    exit;
  m_border_color    := brd_col;
  m_shape.Pen.Color := m_border_color;
end;

procedure TGEdit.setBorderWidth( brd_wid : integer );
begin
  if (m_border_width = brd_wid) or (brd_wid < 0) then
    exit;
  m_border_width    := brd_wid;
  m_shape.Pen.Width := m_border_width;
end;
```

But when I put component on form the Shape doesn't drawn. Where is an error in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TShape` is a `TGraphicControl` derived control, and as such can never appear on top of a `TWinControl` derived control other than its own `Parent`.

Your `TGEdit` constructor has an error in it.  `Self.Parent` is nil in the constructor, so you are assigning a nil `Parent` to the `TShape`, and thus it will never be visible.

If you want the `TShape` to have the same `Parent` as your `TGEdit` then you need to override the virtual `SetParent()` method, which is called after construction is finished.  You will also have to override the virtual `SetBounds()` method to make sure your `TShape` moves around whenever your `TGEdit` moves around, eg:

```
type
  TGEdit = class(TEdit)
  ...
  protected
    ...
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
    ...
  end;

procedure TGEdit.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if m_shape <> nil then
    m_shape.SetBounds(Self.Left - m_border_width, Self.Top - m_border_width, Self.Width + (2*m_border_width), Self.Height + (2*m_border_width));
end;

procedure TGEdit.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  if m_shape <> nil then
    m_shape.Parent := Self.Parent;
end;
```

Now, with all of that said, there is an alternative solution - derive your component from `TCustomPanel` instead and have it create a `TEdit` on top of itself.  You can set the Panel's color, bordering, etc as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the method is working! But when TEdit hasn't borders the vertical alignment of the text inside it is ugly! How to correct text vertical position? (This also concern you proposal about using TPanel.)

Comment: Also it is no necessity to destroy TShape in destructor.

Comment: The border width (width of TShape) is not changed.